# How to make a join using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria, detachedcriteria

I have a question regarding join between 2 entities using hql.

Starting on a userProfile, I have to retrieve the name of the role associated to this userProfile. So I need to make a join in order to get it in the role table.

I have the following class UserProfile :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_PROFILES")
public class UserProfile extends VersionedObject implements Serializable {

  public static final int CAID_LENGTH = 64;

  @Column(nullable=false, length=CAID_LENGTH)
  private String caid;

  @Column(length=255)
  private String description;

  @CollectionOfElements
  @JoinTable(
      name="USER_ROLES",
      joinColumns={
          @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
          @JoinColumn(name="user_v_no", referencedColumnName="v_no")
  })
  @Column(name="role_id")
  private Set<Integer> roleIds;
```

Here is the Role.java class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ROLES")
public class Role extends VersionedObject implements Serializable {

  @Column(nullable=false, length=255)
  private String name;
  @Column(length=255)
  private String description;

  @CollectionOfElements
  @JoinTable(
      name="ROLES_RIGHTS",
      joinColumns={
          @JoinColumn(name="role_v_no", referencedColumnName="v_no"),
          @JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  })

  private Set<Right> rights;
```

Do you know how can I make a join based on the `private Set<Integer> roleIds` within the userProfile.java to retrieve the associated role in order to retrieve the name?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you are representing your tables, instead of representing real world object relationships. By that, I mean that you should *not* map the ID of Roles, but the actual Role class.

So, instead of mapping this:

```
private Set<Integer> roleIds;
```

Try to map this:

```
private Set<Role> roles;
```

You did correctly for the `Set<Right> rights`, so, not sure why you mapped the IDs instead of objects in `Set<Integer> roleIds`.

After that, you should be able to simply do `userProfile.roles`, retrieving a full set of Roles, including its names.